# How to embed md5 sum of sentence in the sentence?

Tags: hash, cryptography, md5sum, quine

For example, how do I solve for x such that md5(“The md5 of this sentence is [x].” = x? Is this possible with a reasonable amount of effort?

Are there any other common cryptographic hashes that make this easier or harder?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of not programming

Comment: Try it yourself with some very short hash functions, say MD5 truncated to only 16 bits. You will see that there is no guarantee that there are any solutions at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Is this possible with a reasonable amount of effort?*

No, at best brute force 2^128, at worst no.

*Are there any other common cryptographic hashes that make this easier or harder?*

SHA-3 or Skein allow a specified output size with a short output it would be easier. A longer hash output would be harder.